# How to determine matched filter coefficients(impulse response) based on various required signal templates

Tags: matlab, filter, coefficients

I want to implement Matched filter to maximize the SNR of receiving signal.
in my system ,my receiver get various pulses in various shapes , I know the shape of the required pulse and i want to filter the receive signal using Matched filter and get my required pules with maximum SNR.

Theoretically, I need to use my time reversed required signal template as a impulse response of the filter.

Actually I have a lot of pulses getting into my receiver and i want to maximize the required pulse SNR.

I record a few pulses and the noise added to my required pulse is affect my impulse response to be used in the Matched filter.

My question is : based on my records , how should I determine the Matched filter coefficients( /impulse response)? I am actually need to measure the variance between my records , or mean those records....

Any suggestions for other methods to get my Matched filter impulse response?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to MathWorks' documentation on Matched Filtering from this link : 
https://www.mathworks.com/help/phased/ug/matched-filtering.html

In the documentation, at the subsection **Matched Filtering to Improve SNR for Target Detection** it is stated as *This example shows how to improve the SNR by performing matched filtering.* which I believe the topic you are looking for and can give you a starting point.